# Exact Difference between two dates in days and hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I want to get exact time in days and hours between two dates something like between          `Thu Jul 18 11:30:00 +0000 2013` and `Sat Jul 20 10:30:00 +0000 2013`. There is difference of `1 day and 23 hours`.                                                                             The Rails' ActionView module includes two methods

```
(1) distance_of_time_in_words
(2) distance_of_time_in_words_to_now
```

but they return result like 1 day or 2 day i need hours also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a gem for that: `time_diff` !

https://rubygems.org/gems/time_diff

It will display the time difference and you can even format the output. Example:

`'%y, %M, %w, %d and %h:%m:%s'` will return: `'1 year, 2 months, 3 weeks, 4 days and 12:05:52'`

The syntax is also very straighforward:

```
> Time.diff(Time.parse('2010-03-06 12:30:00'), Time.parse('2011-03-07 12:30:30'), '%y, %d and %h:%m:%s')
=> {:year => 1, :month => 0, :week => 0, :day => 0, :hour => 18, :minute => 0, :second => 30, :diff => '1 year and 18:00:30'}
```

You should be able to get what you need out of this.

Happy coding !

Comment: I am facing compatibility issue in gem "time_diff". However it installed successfully still have compatibility issue i am using Rails 2.3.2 and ruby ruby 1.8.7. Can you help Regard this

Comment: It seems time_diff uses `ActiveSupport v3.0.1` which was released in October 14, 2010 (see `Gemfile.lock`) when the Rails version you're using was released prior to that: 2.3.2 March 15, 2009. There is probably some incompatibility there. So there are two solutions: update Rails or the gem itself I think. The Ruby version is no problem (it is used by the gem itself). And, just for your info, know that 1.8.7 is not supported anymore: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7/ . Hope this helps !

Comment: Actually for my project I am using Rails 2.3.2. And i can not upgrade it. So i want to know is it possible to use time_diff gem with rails 2.3.2.

Comment: As said un my previous comment, `ActiveSupport v3.0.1` seems required by the gem. You'll have to check what is missing in your version of rails 2.3.2 and update whatever needs to be. I don't think you'll be able to make it work without any tinkering with the code. Maybe it would be helpful if you posted what is the error that is returned when you try to get the gem working.

Comment: i have gone through the time_diff gem source code and directly use it in my project and work for me.. THanks for your support...actually i have used code as it is from time_diff gem and did not install it and its working fine...

Comment: time_diff has issues. It seems to assume months are 30 days long which they are not. Depending on your use case this might be a problem or not. Definitely a problem if you also need to count months and years between dates.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use any gem then you can simply do following calculations to get exact difference of minutes and seconds too -

```
t1 = Time.now #date1
t2 = (Time.now - 10.hours) #date2

seconds = (t1.to_i - t2.to_i)
days = seconds / 86400;
hours = seconds / 3600;
minutes = (seconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60;
seconds = (seconds - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60));
```

Answer (score 6):

The plugin [dotiw](https://github.com/radar/dotiw) might be useful to solve this issue.

dotiw is a plugin for Rails that overrides the default distance_of_time_in_words and provides a more accurate output.

Comment: yep i have used dotiw but seems like this affecting other parts of my project so i need some alternate solution than dotiw. But Thanks for the solution..

Comment: @sumit If the conflict is that dotiw changes the output of distance_of_time_in_words, then the :vague option can be added to use the original format yet distance_of_time_in_words_hash is still available.

Answer (score 1):

```
date_1 = DateTime.parse("Thu Jul 18 11:30:00 +0000 2013")
date_2 = DateTime.parse("Sat Jul 20 10:30:00 +0000 2013")

difference_in_hours =  (date_2.to_time - date_1.to_time) / 60 / 60
```

Comment: This Solution can be Useful to me but its giving me wrong no of hours between two dates like between "Thu, 18 Jul 2013 11:30:00 +0000" and "Wed Jul 17 06:31:44 +0000 2013" its Returning                                                     "-72.42713155"  Can you explain how 72 hour difference is possible between two consecutive dates Or Please give Hints how can i make it work correct.

Comment: Following the above code should return exactly `47`. What exactly are you running to get `-72.42713155`? Also, I updated my answer above.

Comment: the above example is giving 47 you are right. But if you take difference between two dates which has much difference than its giving false no of hours..... Well Thnaks for your support...

Comment: Give me whatever two examples dates you are using that don't work, and I'll work it out for you.